# Converting the single date format in to the oracle data type

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a column in the oracle database with data type  `varchar`, this column is accepting the different types of the data as follows

```
03/01/2012
01 JANUARY 2012
1  FEBRUARY 2013
13-JAN-2012
03/01/2012 MM-ss
```

now I want to convert in to the one single format as 'DD/MM/YY or else any one of the standard format

Tha

Comment: You want to convert all the dates in this column to a single format?

Comment: If you are wanting the data just to be constrained to DD/MM/YY you will need to change the data type to DATE.                               ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name DATE

Comment: @SEBBINFIELD Will that cause an error if the existing dates are not all formatted?

Comment: @BrianRobbins When modifying a tables column datatype you may want to export the rows, redefine the table and then re-import you data. Or- 1 - Create the new column at the end of the table.
2 - Run an update to populate the new table column
3 - Drop the old table column
4 - Re-name the new column to the original column name

Comment: My first thought was to export and redefine. Good thoughts :)

Answer (score 1):

As discussed above:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name DATE
```

To add new column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name add (column_name DATE);
```

To drop column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name drop column col_name1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a methodical approach.  Step 1 is to add a new column to your table with a date datatype.  Step 2 is to modify all applicable applications so that they use the new column, not the old one.  Then do a series of update queries.

```
update yourTable
set newDateColumn = to_date(oldVarcharColumn, 'mask')
where newDateColumn is null
and regexp_like (oldVarcharColumn, pattern)
```

Finally drop the oldVarcharColumn.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, if you need to convert the date values into a single data type in the table, then you can follow a step-by-step approach.

Since you have various patterns of values in your existing column, you can use a `CASE` statement in conjunction with the regular expressions (`REGEXP_LIKE`) to convert the values, as below:

```
SELECT
  text_date, 
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(text_date, '^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$') THEN to_date(text_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(text_date, '^\d{2} ([A-Z]|[a-z])+ \d{4}$') THEN to_date(text_date, 'DD MONTH YYYY')
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(text_date, '^\d{1}  ([A-Z]|[a-z])+ \d{4}$') THEN to_date(text_date, 'DD  MONTH YYYY')
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(text_date, '^\d{2}-([A-Z]|[a-z]){3}-\d{4}$') THEN to_date(text_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(text_date, '^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} MM-ss$') THEN to_date(text_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY "MM-ss"')
    ELSE NULL
  END date_value
FROM text_dates
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(text_date, '^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$')
OR REGEXP_LIKE(text_date, '^\d{2} ([A-Z]|[a-z])+ \d{4}$')
OR REGEXP_LIKE(text_date, '^\d{1}  ([A-Z]|[a-z])+ \d{4}$')
OR REGEXP_LIKE(text_date, '^\d{2}-([A-Z]|[a-z]){3}-\d{4}$')
OR REGEXP_LIKE(text_date, '^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} MM-ss$')
ORDER BY text_date;
```

In the above query, each pattern is detected using a regular expression.

See <kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/542e6c/25)</kbd>.

**Reference**:

[REGEXP_LIKE Condition on Oracle® Database SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501)

[Regular Expressions Cheat Sheet on PSOUG.ORG](http://psoug.org/snippet/Regular-Expressions---Regexp-Cheat-Sheet_856.htm)